# Customize Bootstrap checkboxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm using Bootstrap in my Angular application and all other styles are working like they should, but checkbox style doesn't. It just look like plain old checkbox.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please log in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">User name</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="loginUser.Username" type="username" name="username" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="loginUser.Password" type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <a *ngIf="register == false" (click)="registerState()">Register</a>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
         <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rememberMe" name="rememberme"> Remember me
         </label>
    </div>
    <button *ngIf="register == false" (click)="login()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

What it looks like:

[image: checkbox style without bootstrap]

What I want it to look like with Bootstrap style:

[image: bootstrap styled checkbox]

Comment: Bootstrap (before 4) doesn't have a specific style for checkboxes, the second one is the style of macOS/OS X

Comment: @PaoloForgia both are macOS/OS X checkboxes. One is when page was zoom in about 110% and second is 100% zoom. This was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280910/8081009

Comment: In all cases you have to hide the original checkbox and add some customized "fake" checkbox. I found the solution w3schools provides the easiest:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp
and it comes pretty close to your requirements.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since Bootstrap 3 doesn't have a style for [checkboxes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios) I found [a custom made](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/animated-radios-amp-checkboxes-nojs) that goes really well with Bootstrap style.

## Checkboxes

```css
.checkbox label:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.checkbox .cr {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: .25em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.checkbox .cr .cr-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]+.cr>.cr-icon {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.cr>.cr-icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.cr {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Default checkbox -->
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="">
   <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
   Option one
   </label>
</div>

<!-- Checked checkbox -->
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
   <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
   Option two is checked by default
   </label>
</div>

<!-- Disabled checkbox -->
<div class="checkbox disabled">
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="" disabled>
   <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
   Option three is disabled
   </label>
</div>
```

## Radio

```css
.checkbox label:after,
.radio label:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.checkbox .cr,
.radio .cr {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: .25em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.radio .cr {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .cr .cr-icon,
.radio .cr .cr-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 13%;
}

.radio .cr .cr-icon {
  margin-left: 0.04em;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"],
.radio label input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]+.cr>.cr-icon,
.radio label input[type="radio"]+.cr>.cr-icon {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.cr>.cr-icon,
.radio label input[type="radio"]:checked+.cr>.cr-icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.cr,
.radio label input[type="radio"]:disabled+.cr {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Default radio -->
<div class="radio">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="o3" value="">
   <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-circle"></i></span>
   Option one
   </label>
</div>

<!-- Checked radio -->
<div class="radio">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="o3" value="" checked>
   <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-circle"></i></span>
   Option two is checked by default
   </label>
</div>

<!-- Disabled radio -->
<div class="radio disabled">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="o3" value="" disabled>
   <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-circle"></i></span>
   Option three is disabled
   </label>
</div>
```

## Custom icons

You can choose your own icon between the ones from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons-glyphs) or [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free) by changing `[icon name]` with your icon.

```
<span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon [icon name]"></i>
```

For example:

- `glyphicon glyphicon-remove` for Bootstrap, or
- `fa fa-bullseye` for Font Awesome

```css
.checkbox label:after,
.radio label:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.checkbox .cr,
.radio .cr {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: .25em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.radio .cr {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox .cr .cr-icon,
.radio .cr .cr-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
}

.radio .cr .cr-icon {
  margin-left: 0.04em;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"],
.radio label input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]+.cr>.cr-icon,
.radio label input[type="radio"]+.cr>.cr-icon {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.cr>.cr-icon,
.radio label input[type="radio"]:checked+.cr>.cr-icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox label input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.cr,
.radio label input[type="radio"]:disabled+.cr {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
   <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
   Bootstrap - Custom icon checkbox
   </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="o3" value="" checked>
   <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-bullseye"></i></span>
   Font Awesome - Custom icon radio checked by default
   </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="o3" value="">
   <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-bullseye"></i></span>
   Font Awesome - Custom icon radio
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good but only works if the checkbox is inside the label, and is difficult to adapt to other layouts like the label being on the left, or on a different line.

Answer (score 19):

You have to use Bootstrap version 4 with the `custom-*` classes to get this style:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- example code of the bootstrap website -->
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-description">Check this custom checkbox</span>
</label>

<!-- your code with the custom classes of version 4 -->
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rememberMe" name="rememberme" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Remember me</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

> **Documentation:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios-1

---

**Custom checkbox style on Bootstrap version 3?**
Bootstrap version 3 doesn't have custom checkbox styles, but you can use your own. In this case: [How to style a checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4148499/3840840)

These custom styles are only available since version 4.

Comment: It seems like lot of work. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/ I tried to change from 3 to 4 and my whole UI got broken. I will check that link now.

Comment: change the color of the components with the scss variable `$component-active-bg: green`

Answer (score 11):

```css
/* The customcheck */
.customcheck {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.customcheck input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.customcheck:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.customcheck input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #02cf32;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.customcheck input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.customcheck .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1></br>
 
        <label class="customcheck">One
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="customcheck">Two
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="customcheck">Three
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="customcheck">Four
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: is this answer copied from this page? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: Thank you, for my requirement, this is the perfect answer....

Answer (score 5):

Here you have an example styling checkboxes and radios using Font Awesome 5 free[

```css
  /*General style*/
  .custom-checkbox label, .custom-radio label {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
 .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] ,.custom-radio input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    right: 9000px;
  }
   /*Custom checkboxes style*/
  .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]+.label-text:before {
    content: "\f0c8";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.label-text:before {
    content: "\f14a";
    color: #2980b9;
    animation: effect 250ms ease-in;
  }
  .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.label-text {
    color: #aaa;
  }
  .custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.label-text:before {
    content: "\f0c8";
    color: #ccc;
  }

   /*Custom checkboxes style*/
  .custom-radio input[type="radio"]+.label-text:before {
    content: "\f111";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  .custom-radio input[type="radio"]:checked+.label-text:before {
    content: "\f192";
    color: #8e44ad;
    animation: effect 250ms ease-in;
  }

  .custom-radio input[type="radio"]:disabled+.label-text {
    color: #aaa;
  }

  .custom-radio input[type="radio"]:disabled+.label-text:before {
    content: "\f111";
    color: #ccc;
  }

  @keyframes effect {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    25% {
      transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    75% {
      transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2a10ab39d6.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form>
    <h2>1. Customs Checkboxes</h2>
    <div class="custom-checkbox">
      <div class="form-check">
        <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check" checked> <span class="label-text">Option 01</span>
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check"> <span class="label-text">Option 02</span>
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check"> <span class="label-text">Option 03</span>
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check" disabled> <span class="label-text">Option 04</span>
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form>
    <h2>2. Customs Radios</h2>
    <div class="custom-radio">

      <div class="form-check">
        <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" checked> <span class="label-text">Option 01</span>
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio"> <span class="label-text">Option 02</span>
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio"> <span class="label-text">Option 03</span>
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" disabled> <span class="label-text">Option 04</span>
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the style you're after is actually just the Mac OS checkbox style, so it will look radically different on other devices.

In fact both screenshots you linked show what checkboxes look like on Mac OS in Chrome, the grey one is shown at non-100% zoom levels.

Comment: Actually this is the reason in my case. I have no idea that I have touch to the zoom level. When I zoom back to 100% style become what I was looking for. But still custom style will be always better in my case that I know it looks always the same.

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap 5, if the switch/checkbox is not styled, add `appearance` in your css file.

For example:

```
.form-switch, .form-check {    
    .form-check-input {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
    }
}
```