# Increasing the size of a bootstrap checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am creating a simple check box with the code from the official bootstrap documentation:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

I am wondering how to make the checkbox larger than it currently is? I have tried editing the css of `customCheck` and changing the height and width properties, but that does not increase the size of the box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: You can not increase height of the native checkbox and radio input. But you can make custom checkbox and radio input. Doing so, you are free to customise it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize Bootstrap checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279398/customize-bootstrap-checkboxes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a good idea to change bootstrap components dimensions, you should change variables in bootstrap but it means to recompile library.
Anyway what you want can be done i this way:

```
.custom-control-label::before ,.custom-control-label::after{width:20px; height:20px}
```

Answer (score 68):

I added classes like `*-sm, *-md, *-lg, *-xl` for the bootstrap switch.

Here I made **all resolutions switch** with one @mixin ( @mixin is very similar to JS functions but it does not return anything ).

---

## For Bootstrap 4

`custom-switch-sm, custom-switch-md, custom-switch-lg, custom-switch-xl`

**SCSS:** https://codepen.io/nisharg/pen/VwLbYvv

**CSS:** https://codepen.io/nisharg/pen/mdJmywW

**LIVE SNIPPET (CSS)**

```css
/* for sm */

.custom-switch.custom-switch-sm .custom-control-label {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-sm .custom-control-label::before {
    height: 1rem;
    width: calc(1rem + 0.75rem);
    border-radius: 2rem;
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-sm .custom-control-label::after {
    width: calc(1rem - 4px);
    height: calc(1rem - 4px);
    border-radius: calc(1rem - (1rem / 2));
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-sm .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::after {
    transform: translateX(calc(1rem - 0.25rem));
}

/* for md */

.custom-switch.custom-switch-md .custom-control-label {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-md .custom-control-label::before {
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: calc(2rem + 0.75rem);
    border-radius: 3rem;
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-md .custom-control-label::after {
    width: calc(1.5rem - 4px);
    height: calc(1.5rem - 4px);
    border-radius: calc(2rem - (1.5rem / 2));
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-md .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::after {
    transform: translateX(calc(1.5rem - 0.25rem));
}

/* for lg */

.custom-switch.custom-switch-lg .custom-control-label {
    padding-left: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-lg .custom-control-label::before {
    height: 2rem;
    width: calc(3rem + 0.75rem);
    border-radius: 4rem;
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-lg .custom-control-label::after {
    width: calc(2rem - 4px);
    height: calc(2rem - 4px);
    border-radius: calc(3rem - (2rem / 2));
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-lg .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::after {
    transform: translateX(calc(2rem - 0.25rem));
}

/* for xl */

.custom-switch.custom-switch-xl .custom-control-label {
    padding-left: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-xl .custom-control-label::before {
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: calc(4rem + 0.75rem);
    border-radius: 5rem;
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-xl .custom-control-label::after {
    width: calc(2.5rem - 4px);
    height: calc(2.5rem - 4px);
    border-radius: calc(4rem - (2.5rem / 2));
}

.custom-switch.custom-switch-xl .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::after {
    transform: translateX(calc(2.5rem - 0.25rem));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-sm">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Default Unchcked Switch</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-sm">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch2" checked>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">Default Checked Switch</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-md">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch3">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch3">Default Unchcked Switch</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-md">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch4" checked>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch4">Default Checked Switch</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-lg">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch5">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch5">Default Unchcked Switch</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-lg">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch6" checked>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch6">Default Checked Switch</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-xl">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch7">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch7">Default Unchcked Switch</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-xl">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch8" checked>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch8">Default Checked Switch</label>
</div>
```

---

## For Bootstrap 5

`form-switch-sm, form-switch-md, form-switch-lg, form-switch-xl`

**SCSS**: https://codepen.io/nisharg/pen/gOPLOYY

**CSS**: https://codepen.io/nisharg/pen/ExPNxYE

**LIVE SNIPPET (CSS)**

```css
.form-check-input {
  clear: left;
}

.form-switch.form-switch-sm {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem; /* JUST FOR STYLING PURPOSE */
}

.form-switch.form-switch-sm .form-check-input {
  height: 1rem;
  width: calc(1rem + 0.75rem);
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.form-switch.form-switch-md {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; /* JUST FOR STYLING PURPOSE */
}

.form-switch.form-switch-md .form-check-input {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: calc(2rem + 0.75rem);
  border-radius: 3rem;
}

.form-switch.form-switch-lg {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem; /* JUST FOR STYLING PURPOSE */
}

.form-switch.form-switch-lg .form-check-input {
  height: 2rem;
  width: calc(3rem + 0.75rem);
  border-radius: 4rem;
}

.form-switch.form-switch-xl {
  margin-bottom: 2rem; /* JUST FOR STYLING PURPOSE */
}

.form-switch.form-switch-xl .form-check-input {
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: calc(4rem + 0.75rem);
  border-radius: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-sm">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-sm">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-md">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-md">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-lg">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-lg">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-xl">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-xl">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. I could reply at first to my project.

Comment: This should be incorporated into official bootstrap.

Comment: This creates an issue with the label (.form-check-label) not being on the same level as the switch

Answer (score 27):

## FOR ALL BOOTSTRAP VERSIONS

## No extra CSS/SCSS

Actually, the solution is quite simple, either you apply custom css/scss whatever to make the button bigger OR

You can use the [`transform: scale();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale()) property of css on the switch to increase the size of the button, and trust me this is the easiest way to solve the problem and it works.

```html
<div class="form-check form-switch py-5">

  <!-- Size of the default switch will increase 1.8 times -->
  <input class="form-check-input mx-2" 
         type="checkbox" 
         role="switch" 
         id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" 
         style="transform: scale(1.8);">

  <label class="form-check-label" 
         for="flexSwitchCheckDefault" 
         id="AucTu">Autocomplete Turned Off</label>
</div>
```

PS. You dont need to add custom css/scss just dont forget to add some margin from the switch, or padding from the div (or somepart of it will get hidden) :)

Answer (score 9):

In bootstrap 4, if you want to change or increase custom switch (a beautiful switch from iOS), you should dive into bootstrap's css file and change its dimensions of a class of ***custom-switch***.
[image]
html code as following:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="switchA" name="switch">
 <label class="custom-control-label" for="switchA">Custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

> In boostrap.css (version 4.3.1 and not minified) file, you should find
>   the ***custom-switch*** class and change the following parameters in
>   the below. You must ***delete all the comments*** I added on.

```
.custom-switch {
  padding-left: 2.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem; // added for positioning
}

.custom-control-label { // added for alignment with the switch
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::before {
  left: -2.25rem;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 3.5rem;    // it was 1.75rem before. Sliding way is longer than before.
  pointer-events: all;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::after {
  top: calc(0.25rem + 2px);
  left: calc(-2.25rem + 2px);
  width: calc(2rem - 4px);   // it was calc(1rem - 4px) before. Oval is bigger than before.
  height: calc(2rem - 4px);  // it was calc(1rem - 4px) before. Oval is bigger than before.
  background-color: #adb5bd;
  border-radius: 2rem; //   it was 0.5rem before. Oval is bigger than before.
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .custom-switch .custom-control-label::after {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1.5rem); //translateX(0.75rem);
  transform: translateX(1.5rem); //translateX(0.75rem);
}
```

> After copied these code to Bootstrap file, **you must delete all**
>   **comments** I put in. Otherwise, It won't increase the size. I hope you enjoy
>   your a bigger pretty switch now.

Answer (score 7):

With Bootstrap 5, there is an elegant solution to adjust the size of checkboxes by using the predefined font-size classes (fs-x) provided by the framework. Here is an example of code:

```
<div class="form-check fs-3">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
            Default radio
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check fs-4">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
            Default radio
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check fs-5">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
            Default radio
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check fs-6 mb-3">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
            Default radio
        </label>
    </div>
```

And the result :

[image: Different size of checkboxes]

Answer (score 5):

It's probably best to have your own file and change the css variables for the dimensions of the switch:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";

$custom-control-indicator-size: 1.5rem;
$custom-switch-width: $custom-control-indicator-size * 1.75;
$custom-switch-indicator-border-radius: $custom-control-indicator-size / 2;
$custom-switch-indicator-size: subtract(
  $custom-control-indicator-size,
  $custom-control-indicator-border-width * 4
);

@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 4):

## Bootstrap 5

I reworked the css from Nisharg Shah such that the Text is now nicely aligned with the switch for the Bootstrap V5 example.
Therefore, I took a look into the Bootstrap 5 css sources and increased all attributes that seem involved into sizing: `padding-left`, `hight`, `margin-left`, `width` and `padding-top`.
I think the result looks better and aligned with the default switch appearance style.

CSS and HTML:

```css
.form-switch.form-switch-md {
    padding-left: 4.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
}

.form-switch.form-switch-md .form-check-input {
    margin-left: -4.5em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 4em;
}

.form-switch.form-switch-md .form-check-label {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.form-switch.form-switch-lg {
    padding-left: 8.5em;
    height: 4.5em;
}

.form-switch.form-switch-lg .form-check-input {
    margin-left: -8.5em;
    height: 4em;
    width: 8em;
}

.form-switch.form-switch-lg .form-check-label {
    padding-top: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Original switch unchecked</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Original switch checked</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-md">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Medium switch unchecked</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-md">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Medium switch checked</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-lg">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Large switch unchecked</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch form-switch-lg">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Large switch checked</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This class `.custom-switch-adaptive` will make the switch adapt to text size and include the label text inside.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dfmbe60u/13/)

P.S. [A similar feature will be added in Bootstrap v5](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30087)

[image]

**SCSS**

```
.custom-switch.custom-switch-adaptive {
  padding-left: 0;

  .custom-control-label {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    color: $text-muted;
    border: 1px solid $text-muted;
    background-color: $light;
    transition: background-color 200ms;

    &::before {
      content: none;
    }
    &::after {
      position: absolute;
      height: 1em;
      top: 0.2em;
      left: 0.2em;
      width: 1em;
      border-radius: 1em;

      transition: left 200ms;
    }
  }


  .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label {
    color: $white;
    background-color: $success;
    border-color: $success;

    &::after {
      background-color: $white;
      left: calc(100% - 1.2em);

      transform: none;
      -webkit-transform: none;
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group h1">
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-adaptive">
    <input id="test4" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <label for="test4" class="custom-control-label">h1 text size</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks amazing, but is there a way to perform this using regular CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get it done in bootstrap, its easy.
Add a div container first with `btn-group-toggle` to use buttons in group (that is if you want.).

Add `p-3` or `p-5` class in label to expand it to your liking

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary p-3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="customCheck" name="example1"> Check this custom checkbox
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please explain :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using custom css

```css
.custom-checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::before,
.custom-checkbox-lg .custom-control-label::after {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

.custom-checkbox-lg .custom-control-label {
  margin: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" name="example1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-checkbox-lg">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2" name="example1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

```css
.custom-control-label::before, 
.custom-control-label::after {
  width: 2.25rem !important;
  height: 2.25rem !important;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.custom-control-label{
  margin: 1.5rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this while looking for a solution to the same issue but none of the previous answers worked well for me, especially when there was a label with the checkbox/switch.

Started playing around with margins and line heights but it seems that the solution might be much simpler than that - At least with Bootstrap V5, all sizes and margins are set relatively with `"em"`, so changing the font size on the base `form-check` element resizes and aligns everything nicely, with or without the label.

EDIT: Just noticed the bottom margin is a bit off when there is no label, but it's easily fixable by adding an empty label or adjusting the margins/padding manually as needed.

```css
.form-check-lg {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h3>default font size:</h3>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox_1">default</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox_2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox_2">default</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
</div>

<h3>larger font size:</h3>
<div class="form-check form-switch form-check-lg">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox_3">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox_3">large</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-lg">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox_4">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox_4">large</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-switch form-check-lg">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-lg">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution... Just used Bootstrap & FontAvesome....

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ps-3">
  <div class="h3">bootstrap@5.1.3 &  font-awesome/6.2.0</div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label>Label Top</label>
    <span class="form-check form-switch">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch">
      <label class="form-check-label">Label Side</label>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label>Label Top</label>
    <span class="form-check form-switch fa-2x">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch">
      <label class="form-check-label">Label Side</label>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label>Label Top</label>
    <span class="form-check form-switch fa-2x">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch">
      <label class="form-check-label">Label Side</label>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label>Label Top</label>
    <span class="form-check form-switch fa-3x">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch">
      <label class="form-check-label">Label Side</label>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label>Label Top</label>
    <span class="form-check form-switch fa-4x">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch">
      <label class="form-check-label">Label Side</label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```