# How to customize Radio button and check box

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I have created a form and fields are on different Tabs. Here is HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" name="post">
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="container-fluid tab-pane active"><br>
            <h3>Gender</h3>
                <div class="row">
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" />
                        <label for="male"><i class="fas fa-male male"></i></label>

                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" />
                        <label for="female"><i class="fas fa-female female"></i></label>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-gender" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Continue</a>
                </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="menu1" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade"><br>
            <h3>Activity</h3>
                    <input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity1" value="Activity1" />
                    <label for="activity1">Activity1</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="activity" id="activity2" value="Activity2" />
                    <label for="activity2">Activity2</label>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>    
  </form>
```

I am having two problems :

1. I want to hide circles of radio button so that it only shows label and when user click on label it get selected.
2. When user click on any radio button, it should be selected and the page get redirected to next tab that is #menu1 automatically with needing to click on Continue button. I tried to use onclick and onchange but its not working for me.

Comment: there are thousands of sites explaining this, and it's more a designer problem than a coder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize Bootstrap checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279398/customize-bootstrap-checkboxes)

Comment: @MisterJojo No, the suggested question is about customizing checkboxes while my question is about hiding the checkbox/radio.

Comment: In this case use css visibility ...

Comment: Thanks @MisterJojo It worked. Can you please help me in my second question ?

Comment: it should be done with `addEventListener` and `input` event